# Ionic Cordova Build --release not compile css

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic6

When i run ionic in emulator background color black is working
But after i run ionic cordova build android --release my app background back to white.

Can anyone help my problem?
This screenshot on my emulator (when run ionic cordova emulate android --livereload)
[image: screenshoot livereload]

And this is after ionic cordova build android --release

[image: screenshot after build release]

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.1 (C:\Users\fahri\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.2.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.1.1
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 14.1.1
   @angular/cli                  : 14.1.1
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 11.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 5.0.0, (and 3 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.4
   native-run  : 1.6.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (D:\apps\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v16.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 8.11.0
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by dark and light theming.

Inside variables.scss you will have theme variables for devices set with light or dark theming.

You can replace all of the :root styles with the dark styles if that is your desired look.